# How to sort a multiple list by an order list in python?

Tags: python

I have three lists:

```
One = [[[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4], [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4], [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]], 
       [[4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4], [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4], [6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4]]]
Two = [[[1], [2], [3]], 
       [[4], [5], [6]]]
sort_order = [[[5], [1], [3]], 
              [[2], [8], [5]]]
```

I want to sort lists `One` and `Two` by values of `sort_order`. That is, for each element in lists `One` and `Two` to be sorted by the values of the element in the `sort_order`. After sorting lists `One` and `Two` become this:

```
One = [[[2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4], [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]], 
       [[4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4], [6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4], [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4]]]  

Two = [[[2], [3], [1]], 
       [[4], [6], [5]]]
```

Comment: Hi, list Two seems to not change anything?

Comment: What does this mean: "for each element in lists `One` and `Two` to be sorted by the values of the element in the `sort_order`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want … each element in lists "One" and "Two" to be sorted by the values of the element in the **"sort_order"**.

You can produce sort indexes by sorting index ranges by sort order, and then use those indexes to rearrange the list elements.

```
sort_index = [sorted(range(len(l)), key=lambda i: l[i]) for l in sort_order]
# sort_index now contains the needed order elements: [[1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
# with that, we can simply rearrange our lists:
One = [[l[j] for j in i] for l, i in zip(One, sort_index)]
Two = [[l[j] for j in i] for l, i in zip(Two, sort_index)]
```

Alternatively if you want to modify the lists in-place:

```
sort_index = [sorted(range(len(l)), key=lambda i: l[i]) for l in sort_order]
for l, i in zip(One, sort_index): l[:] = [l[j] for j in i]
for l, i in zip(Two, sort_index): l[:] = [l[j] for j in i]
```